# Mongoose.js: force always populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to instruct model to populate ALWAYS a certain field?

Something like, to have "field" populated in any find query:

```
{field: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Ref', populate: true}
```

?

Comment: Although it sounds like it would be a useful feature, I'm not sure you'd really want this option at the schema level. By applying this option you'd never be able to get at the original ObjectId stored in the collection, so it would make updating and saving a document difficult.

Comment: Mongoose is smart enough to automatically extract the ObjectId from a populated sub-object, when you save.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

With Mongoose 4.0, you can use Query Hooks in order to autopopulate whatever you want.

Below example is from [introduction document](http://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-version-40-mongoose-nodejs-odm) by Valeri Karpov.

Definition of Schemas:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

var bandSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  lead: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'person' }
});

var Person = mongoose.model('person', personSchema, 'people');
var Band = mongoose.model('band', bandSchema, 'bands');

var axl = new Person({ name: 'Axl Rose' });
var gnr = new Band({ name: "Guns N' Roses", lead: axl._id });
```

Query Hook to autopopulate:

```
var autoPopulateLead = function(next) {
  this.populate('lead');
  next();
};

bandSchema.
  pre('findOne', autoPopulateLead).
  pre('find', autoPopulateLead);

var Band = mongoose.model('band', bandSchema, 'bands');
```

Answer (score 4):

this plugin is a solution to your question:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate

Comment: This solution is officially referenced in the mongoose docs as at 5.3.9: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 0):

I use query hook to autopopulate, but it not works with `create()` and `save()` for modified fields.
This is my code:

```
var autoPopulate = function(next) {
  this.populate('updated_by','name').populate('created_by','name');
  next();
};

ProjectSchema.pre('findOne', autoPopulate);
ProjectSchema.pre('find', autoPopulate);
```

If I update `Project` only `created_by` is populated

If I create new `Project` both `created_by` and `updated_by` are not populated.

`find` and `findOne` works with no problems.

What should I do to always populate both: `created_by` and `updated_by`?

Comment: I've not tried it but I would assume you would possibly need to use a `post` hook? Perhaps something along the links of `ProjectSchema.post('save', autoPopulate);`

Comment: to save time, you can use this plugin : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate, its adding entire array of refrence document in result of your query...